# True out of sample forecasting with ARIMA in python

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels, forecasting, arima

I'm trying to work out how to conduct true ARIMA out of sample forecasting in Python. I've been googling for DAYS and there doesn't seem to be an answer.

Say I have a dataset of 75 integers. I'm splitting this dataset 70/30 (train/test) as I would do with any ML model, I'm training the model on train, testing against test, but after training and testing I want to predict values 76-80 which do not currently exist. How is this done? Using the build in predict and forecast function beyond the initial dataset throws back errors because my existing dataset isn't long enough.

Do I need to add artificial data to the dataset to enable this?  A point in the right direction would be fantastic.

Apologies for the formatting - submitted via phone.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you're doing that isn't working? It's hard to tell what might be going wrong from your description.